# How to tell pip to keep the most updated version of a lib when installing?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies

my `requirements.txt`:

```
google-api-python-client>=1.6.2
httplib2==0.9.2
...
```

In this case `google-api-python-client` installs the `httplib2=0.14.0`. But I would be overwritten to the older version on the next line.

Of course, in this case, I could act. But there are some cases that a lib depends on another, that depends on another, etc. 
So I'm wondering whether there's a way to tell `pip` to always keep the most recent version of the libs.

like: `pip install -r --keep-most-recent requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This would mean that `pip` should install the latest version of the requirements and their dependencies no matter what the version constraints in `requirements.txt` are, is that right? Impossible as far as I know.

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but maybe you would prefer working with one of these tools:

- [`poetry update`](https://poetry.eustace.io/docs/basic-usage/#updating-dependencies-to-their-latest-versions)
- [`pip-compile --upgrade`](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#updating-requirements)
- [`pipenv update`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/#example-pipenv-upgrade-workflow)